# Why is type erasure concept being used so widely?

Tags: java, scala

*My question is mainly about Scala, but since in the end it's still using JVM with its peculiarities, I also put the `java` tag.*

The more I use parameterized types, the more often the aforementioned question arises. Type erasure brings so much inconvenience (pattern matching like `case x: A[B]` becomes impossible and so on) and there are rather heavy runtime reflection-based workarounds involving extra objects carrying type information in runtime, so I'm (from my user point of view and just of plain curiosity) wondering what decisions did lead to the current lie of the land.

Is carrying complete type everywhere up to runtime information too complicated? Or maybe there are not so much use cases for it so it isn't just being needed that often? Anyway, what are pros and cons of type erasure?

EDIT: I suppose that there are some qualified discussions, or papers, or posts etc about the subject, and I expect answers to be theoretically backed or at least contain some kind of CS-speculations, not just *"runtime types are a bad practice"*. This is *not* the question about whether you did experience problems with that or not - it's about CS basis that lead to the decision.

Comment: I think it's all about maintaining backwards compatibility. If type erasure was not used, this could potentially break old non-generic code.

Comment: IMO, compile-time checks are more valuable, and less inconvenient, than run-time checks.

Comment: So, that's basically a Java 'problem'? Why then Java designers did decide to remove type info in runtime? And what potential problems can it cause if such a feature would be requested by some JSR if that's really important?

Comment: As [a wise person once said](https://twitter.com/d6/status/364821225131872257), "If you meet a Type in the Runtime, kill it". Type erasure isn't just about backward compatibility, and if you're running into situations where it feels like a problem, you may want to reconsider the approach that got you there.

Comment: @TravisBrown, that's something more close to what I wanted to hear, but, as I mentioned previously, I'm interested in theory basics - why it's being considered such a harmful/awful/etc phenomenon and what are the alternatives of what approaches should I use instead and so on. By the way, I don't understand why does this question looks opinion-based-questions-answered because of that particular reason - it's a theoretical question and there should be one definite answer or at least some theoretical basis to it, not just opinions. That's up to answerers if they feel debate-ish, IMO.

Comment: Erasure is simply bad, there's no excuse. Sun did not have enough time/resource, that is the only reason.

Answer (score 4):

> Is carrying complete type everywhere up to runtime information too complicated?

It was done for backward compatability, not to reduce complexity.

> Or maybe there are not so much use cases for it so it isn't just being needed that often?

It isn't need that often but it is confusing when it is needed.

> Anyway, what are pros and cons of type erasure?

Given this has been the state of things since 2004, I suspect it really doesn't matter as it won't change significantly not matter what the pros/cons are.  There is a notional plan to fix this but it is not high priority and might not make it into Java 9.

Comment: If the backward compatibility is the reason, I'm (maybe pure theoretically) interested in motivations of primary decision. Are there any writings on that?

Comment: @cdshines I am sure there was.  I discussed this with Peter Ahe at the time (the main developer) but you are talking about 9 years ago. I did a search and found some broken links. :|

Comment: how does erasure have anything to do with comparability? it should be fine to stuff more type info in newer classes.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu  That would be very complicated for older classes. Which newer classes are you referring to?  ArrayList, HashSet, TreeMap are not newer classes

Comment: are we talking about running old code in newer JVM? then ArrayList etc are newer classes

Comment: @zhong.j.yu ArrayList needs to behave exactly the same as it did.  This means it is not a newer class and you can't just add generics info at runtime. e.g. `list.getClass() == ArrayList.class` How is that going to work if there is more than one ArrayList type? If you have only one ArrayList type, where you going to store generics information?

Comment: the meaning of `class` is not changed - all `ArrayList<X>` types share the same class, the ArrayList.class. we need a new concept `type`, so that we can say `list.getType()== typeof(ArrayList<String>)`.

Comment: @cdshines see the justification given in JLS $4.7 - which I think is incoherent and inconvincing.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu  Can you explain to me how that `ArrayList<Integer>.class == ArrayList<String>.class` but somehow they are not really the same at all as you can get different generic type from them.

Comment: they are different types sharing the same class?